# How to get one field from foreign key in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms

Hi, I have this models:

```
class Mercadoria(models.Model):
    idmercadoria = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Código', primary_key=True)
    referencia = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Referência', max_length=30)
    descricao = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Descrição', max_length=250)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Status', max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['referencia', 'descricao']
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mercadoria'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.referencia + ' - ' + self.descricao

class Produto(models.Model):
    idproduto = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Código', primary_key=True)
    idmercadoria = models.ForeignKey('Mercadoria', db_column='idmercadoria',
                                     verbose_name=u'Mercadoria')
    idtamanho = models.ForeignKey('Tamanho', db_column='idtamanho',
                                  verbose_name=u'Tamanho')
    idcores = models.ForeignKey('Cores', db_column='idcores',
                                verbose_name=u'Cores')
    estoqueatual = models.DecimalField(u'Estoque Atual', max_digits=18,
                                       decimal_places=4, null=False, default=0)
    saldodisponivel = models.DecimalField(u'Saldo Disponível', max_digits=18,
                                          decimal_places=4, null=False, default=0)
    codigobarra = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Código Barras', max_length=13)
    tipoproduto = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Tipo Produto', max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['idmercadoria']
        managed = False
        db_table = 'produto'

class ItensPedido(models.Model):
    idpedido = models.ForeignKey('Pedido', db_column='idpedido',
                                 primary_key=True, default=-1)
    idproduto = models.ForeignKey('Produto', db_column='idproduto')
```

And I have a problem to get "referencia" fields from "Mercadoria" model, using "ItensPedido" model.

The problem is: this database is legacy database, used by your ERP Delphi software, and the person who design the database, is crazy! In my template, I want to get "Mercadoria" models data.

I try this: `{{ itens.idproduto.idmercadoria.descricao.value }}` e `{{ itens.idproduto__idmercadoria__descricao.value }}`  but doesn't work.

I try to modify my view to get `select_related()` work, like this:

```
def get_field_qs(field, **kwargs):
        if field.name == 'idproduto':
            field.queryset = Produto.objects.select_related()

        return field.formfield(**kwargs)

    ItensInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Pedido, ItensPedido, form=PedidoItensForm,
                                               extra=1, fk_name='idpedido', formfield_callback=get_field_qs)
```

and same problem.. doesn't  show me the data from "mercadoria" model.

What`s I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why value? Try `{{ itens.idproduto.idmercadoria.descricao }}` instead.

Comment: @dan-klasson I tried, but same problem, doesn't show nothing. I google for this problem, and I didn't find anything about this, my question is: I can't get FK data in Django?

Comment: You can get it the way you want. Maybe you don't have the data there. Try running the database query that Django generates against your db server. You can use `django-debug-toolbar` to get that query.

Comment: @dan-klasson that`s the problem. django doesn't generate SQL correctly. It not generate using JOIN to the "third" model. I think the only way is to use select_related(), but if I try to modified __init__ of my BaseInlineFormSet, I get error. Even use the django site example.

Comment: Try: `itens = ItensPedido.objects.select_related('Produto', 'Mercadoria') itens.idproduto.idmercadoria.descricao`. That should give you one query.

Comment: @dan-klasson Thats works, but I need to use a inlineformset, how can I pass this to my inlineformset?